# Create Nuget package for different platforms, architectures and .net versions

Tags: c#, .net, dll, nuget

I have a C# 7.3 project `Foo` which I want to publish as a Nuget package. I want my package be available for different architectures (x86 & x64), different platforms (Windows & Linux) and different .Net versions (4.8 framework & 5.0).

`Foo` C# code itself does not contain any architecture-specific code, it consists only of pure C# 7.3. But this project uses my custom platform-specific .dll and .so on Linux (say `ExternalLib.dll` / `ExternalLib.dll.so`). I have one of them for each Windows x64, Windows x86 and etc.

I know that in the NuGet package you place runtime-specific components in `/runtimes` folder structure like `/runtimes/win10-x64/native/ExternalLib.dll`. As [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/supporting-multiple-target-frameworks) says, these will be used only for runtime and I need to specify compile-time references.

I built my `Foo` project in `Any CPU` configuration for each net4.7 and net5.0 and placed each `Foo.dll` in `/lib` folder. So my final folder structure for the module is

```
Project.nuspec
/lib
    /net4.7/Foo.dll
    /net5.0/Foo.dll
/runtimes
         /win10-x64/native/ExternalLib.dll
         /win10-x86/native/ExternalLib.dll
         /linux-x64/native/ExternalLib.dll.so
```

Project.nuspec:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package>
  <metadata>
    /* */
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework=".NETFramework4.8" />
      <group targetFramework="net5.0" />
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

I build a package using the `nuspec pack Project.nuspec` command. There are no errors from it but when I add this package to any .net project and try to use any functionality from it, VS can not find anything from my library.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it. After a research, this is my approach:

1. If you write a C# library, use only .NetStandard, so both .Net and .NetFramework applications can use your library. I used .NetStandard2.0 which can be used from both .Net5.0 and .NetFramework4.8. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) for all compatible versions.
2. Clear NuGet cache
3. Provide xml documentation (optional)

Final .nuspec file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    ...
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework="netstandard2.0" />
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>

  <files>
    <!--Path to documentaion and AnyCPU builded dll-->
    <file src="Doc\Api.xml" target="lib\netstandard2.0"/>
    <file src="bin\x86\Release\netstandard2.0\Foo.dll" target="lib\netstandard2.0"/>

    <!--Path to x86 builded ExternalLib and Foo-->
    <file src="build\x86-Release\ExternalLib.dll" target="runtimes\win-x86\native" />
    <file src="bin\x86\Release\netstandard2.0\Foo.dll" target="runtimes\win-x86\native" />

    <!--Path to x64 builded ExternalLib and Foo-->
    <file src="build\x64-Release\ExternalLib.dll" target="runtimes\win-x64\native" />
    <file src="bin\x64\Release\netstandard2.0\Foo.dll" target="runtimes\win-x64\native" />

    <!--Path to x64 builded ExternalLib(for linux) and Foo(same as windows)-->
    <file src="build\x64-Release\ExternalLib.so" target="runtimes\linux-x64\native\ExternalLib.dll.so" />
    <file src="bin\x64\Release\netstandard2.0\Foo.dll" target="runtimes\linux-x64\native" />
  </files>
</package>
```